# Passing Data between Routes in Angular v7.2 using state. How to retain this value on page refresh

Tags: angular7, angular7-router

Passing Data between Routes in Angular `v7.2` using state.

`this._router.navigateByUrl(AppUtils.API_ROUTE, { state: { hello: 'world' }});`

Value received in component

```
 constructor() {
    console.log(window.history.state.hello);
  }
```

On refresh this value will loose. How to retain this value on page refresh.